# Where to declare a function with angular.element.prototype so that it is accessible throughout the whole app?

Tags: angularjs

Often when I make a directive I include the code snippet below so that it will be easier for me to find elements.

```
if (angular.element.prototype.querySelector === undefined) {
    angular.element.prototype.querySelector = function (selector) {
        return angular.element(this[0].querySelector(selector));
    };
}
```

But I include it every time. My question is where should I declare this once and have it available throughout my whole application to all directives? Where is a good place to do it?

Comment: All you need for that code to work is access to the global angular object. So you can put this anywhere you want, after the angular.[min].js file has been included. For example, where you declare your main module.

Answer (score 0):

You can do module wide configuration with the [config API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module). I more or less follow [this structure](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure), so I have an app.module.js file where I declare my module and it's dependencies, as well as call the config function.  If you have multiple modules you may want to have create a utility lib that you can include in every module.